# Validation in custom view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

Note: Zend Framework 1.12

I'm trying to add support for some HTML5 form elements. I found some snippets online to start me off. Now I need to add support for the new "required" attribute:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
```

Ideally I should be able to just use

```
$element->setRequired(true);
```

and it would add the appropriate tag. But I can't work out how to access this setting from within the helper. So I'm having to add this to the form as well

```
$element->setAttrib('required', '');
```

That's not ideal. How can I make setRequired add the tag automatically? Here's the helper code so far:

```
<?php

class Application_View_Helper_FormEmail extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement {

    public function formEmail($name, $value = null, $attribs = null) {
        $info = $this->_getInfo($name, $value, $attribs);
        extract($info);
        $disabled = '';
        if ($disable) {
            // disabled
            $disabled = ' disabled="disabled"';
        }

        $xhtml = '<input type="email"'
                . ' name="' . $this->view->escape($name) . '"'
                . ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"'
                . ' value="' . $this->view->escape($value) . '"'
                . $disabled
                . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
                . $this->getClosingBracket();

        return $xhtml;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not related to the question: I personally think the way you interpret attributes is moderately ugly, as I used to do it the same way. I encourage you to check out [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65268/is-this-html-helper-good-or-bad) and pay attention to how I've managed to solve this problem, if it bothers you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh never mind, I managed to work it out! Just needed to override the setRequired method in the form element, and add the setAttrib call to it:

```
class Application_Form_Element_Email extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml {

    /**
     * Default form view helper to use for rendering
     * @var string
     */
    public $helper = 'formEmail';

    public function __construct($spec, $options = null) {
        parent::__construct($spec, $options);
        $this->addValidator('Email');
    }

    public function setRequired($flag = true) {
        parent::setRequired($flag);
        parent::setAttrib('required', '');
        return $this;
    }

}
```